# Mathquill - \MathQuillMathField command deleted after using latex() parser

Tags: javascript, mathquill

Im useing the `\MathQuillMathField` command dynamically by user actions on the MathField

example

````
mathFieldSpan = document.getElementById('math-field');
fillInTheBlank = document.getElementById('fill-in-the-blank')
mathField = MQ.MathField(mathFieldSpan);
fillInTheBlank = MQ.StaticMath(document.getElementById('fill-in-the-blank'));

//add new input field with ```\MathQuillMathField``` command to the mathField object.
function mathFieldBtn() {
  mathField.write('\\MathQuillMathField{}');
}

//display the received math input in static mathQuill element - fillInTheBlank
function save() {
  fillInTheBlank.latex(mathField.latex());
}
````

But the `\MathQuillMathField` removed after running `mathField.latex()` method

How can I save the empty field (`\MathQuillMathField`) dynamically and display it in staticMath object?

My goal is to allow partial input in static math expression (let the student fill in the answer for example)